# JXLS: How to migrate jx:out to jxls2?

Tags: jxls

I'm using JXLS1 and due to better performance try to migrate to JXLS2.

In my xls template I use:

```
<jx:out expr="if(SOME COMPARISON) {PRINT THIS} else {PRINT THAT}"/>
```

How is this done with JXLS2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JEXL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html) ternary conditional operator *condition ? if_true : if_false* in the expression.

So for your example a cell can contain

```
${SOME COMPARISON ? PRINT THIS : PRINT THAT}
```